# ScrollView not displaying some UI elements

Tags: android, android-activity, scrollview

I'm developing an application with executes searches via an API on a web server. My search page displays well in portait mode but is too big for landscape mode so I've decided to simply contain all UI elements in a ScrollView by customising the XML in layout-land folder. The problem is, the buttons on the bottom of my form are not being shown in landscape ScrollView. I don't use ScrollView in portrait so maybe that's the problem? The layout XML is like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TableLayout>
            <!-- stuff here is being shown (table with TextViews and EditTexts -->
        </TableLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            <!-- stuff here is not being shown (3 Buttons) -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: There's another </LinearLayout> on the bottom, but it's not being shown in the form (bug?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you forgot to set `android:orientation="vertical"` to your `LinearLayout` (direct child of ScrollView).